# INSERT INTO php MyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

if i have a table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
phone varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and I try to insert a row into it using phpmyadmin with:

```
INSERT INTO users ( 'john', 'johndoe', 'johndoe@gmail.com' , '123456', 'John', 2013-06-07 08:13:28, 2013-06-07 08:13:28)
```

Then why do I get the error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''john', 'johndoe', 'johndoe@gmail.com' , '123456', 'John', 2013-06-07 08:13:28, ' at line 1
```

Comment: Date should be added with qoutes '2013-06-07 08:13:28'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates need to be quoted as well, and you forgot the `VALUES` keyword.

Also, because you are not inserting values for every column, you need to specify which columns you are inserting in. So your statement would become:

```
INSERT INTO users(
  username,
  password,
  email,
  phone,
  name,
  created_at,
  updated_at)
VALUES ( 
  'john', 
  'johndoe', 
  'johndoe@gmail.com' , 
  '123456', 
  'John', 
  '2013-06-07 08:13:28', 
  '2013-06-07 08:13:28')
```

The proof is in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c35d9/1

Answer (score 0):

Date values should have quotes:

```
INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,phone,name,created_at,updated_at) 
       VALUES ('john', 
                'johndoe', 
                'johndoe@gmail.com' , 
                '123456', 
                'John', 
                '2013-06-07 08:13:28', 
                '2013-06-07 08:13:28');
```

UPDATED
Also need to either provide a dummy value for the auto_increment column, or specify column names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns that you are inserting: try

```
INSERT INTO users
  (
username,
password,
email,
phone,
name,
created_at_timestamp,
updated_at_timestamp)
VALUES
  (
'john', 
'johndoe', 
'johndoe@gmail.com' , 
'123456', 
'John', 
'2013-06-07 08:13:28', 
'2013-06-07 08:13:28'
  )
```